# JWT + Spring Security sem autenticação

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Boa tarde pessoal.
Possuo uma aplicação onde recebo um token JWT, o login é tratato em uma aplicação a parte e nesse token recebo os roles.
Preciso utilizar o Spring Security para validar os mesmo e tratar a permissão de acesso os endpoints e caso o acesso seja permitido envio um objeto para ser utilizado pelo sistema.
Montei um código onde faz o que quero, mas não sei se foi a melhor maneira.
Fiquei com essa duvida, porque o objeto que necessito eu inclui dentro do detail da classe authentication:

```
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("");
    final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    authentication.setDetails("bla bla bla")));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Como é possivel verificar no código eu não utilizei nenhum dado para validar o login(pelo fato do mesmo não ser tratado nesse aplicação).
Não sei se essa é uma boa abordagem, se alguem conseguir me ajudar com uma ideia melhor ou souber qual a pratica correta para esse cenario agradeço.

Vlwww

[]'s